# Regenerate Azure Application Insights Instrumentation Key

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Potentially our Application Insights Instrumentation Key got compromised. Is there a way to regenerate instrumentation key without creating a new Application Insights resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to generate the key currently, if you want to improve it, you could post the idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights).

Refer to this similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1885d4d5-23c6-40ec-82f7-32ffa0d268d8/azure-application-insights-chagingregenerating-instrumentation-key

Comment: both links are not working